# Assign score based on percentage range in function in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (dat) with 96 observations and 9 variables.
With the values of 9th variable (Knockdown_percent), I am trying to assign a score between 0 - 10. 
 Score table:

```
Score: percent_range
10: >95
9: 85 to 95
8: 75 to 85
7: 70 to 75
6: 60 to 69
5: 50 to 59
4: 40 to 49
3: 30 to 39
2: 20 to 29
1: 10 to 19
0: < 9
```

For example if the knockdown_percent is < 9, score: 0; 10 to 19 score: 1; 20 to 29 score 2 and so on... 
I am trying to do this in R and have couple of questions:
a) Can I get some help in writing a functions for the above calculation.
b) Is there a built-in function to do the same in R 
b) How I can append the new scores column to the existing data frame (dat) as 10th variable.
Below I am showing the part of data frame.

```
X.S_No Sequence   Pos GCper    qPCR1    qPCR2 Avg_qPCR SD_qPCR Knockdown_percent
1 1_1 TACATG      149    53    0.856    0.856    0.856   0.000              14.4
2 1_2 GAGGAT      116    58    0.686    0.710    0.698   0.017              30.2
3 1_3 CAGTTC        5    53    0.452    0.662    0.557   0.148              44.3
```

Sample code:

```
  compute_score <- function (x){
  n <- length(x)
  score <- 0
  for (i in 1:n){
    if (!is.na(x[i] <= 9 & x[i] >= 0)){
      score <- score + 0
    }
    else if (!is.na(x[i] >= 10 & x[i] <= 19)){
      score <- score + 1
    }
    return (score)
  }
}
compute_score(dat[,"Knockdown_percent"])
```

**Desired output:**

```
X.S_No Sequence   Pos GCper    qPCR1    qPCR2 Avg_qPCR SD_qPCR Knockdown_percent  Score
    1 1_1 TACATG      149    53    0.856    0.856    0.856   0.000              14.4  1
    2 1_2 GAGGAT      116    58    0.686    0.710    0.698   0.017              30.2  3
    3 1_3 CAGTTC        5    53    0.452    0.662    0.557   0.148              44.3  4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Check out the `cut` function. It will create factor levels based on a continuous variable. It may be useful for creating the rank scores.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
breaks <- c(seq(0, 70, by = 10), 75, 85, 95, 100)
as.numeric(cut(dat$Knockdown_percent, breaks, right = FALSE)) - 1
```

Comment: Great! <br> Thank you @Tad Dallas and Patrick Li for your suggestions. <br> It worked :)